# Entity Framework timeouts when transaction is running

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a long request, which is importing data into the system using transaction.The problem is that when single transaction is running, in that period other requests to the tables that it is using are blocked and are running forever and ending with Timeout Exceptions

> The wait operation timed out

How can I allow to read data normally, even if transaction is running there.

P.S. I don't think that it is a SQL pessimistic data lock, because in transaction period I'm able to select data from tables using SQL Management Studio.

Comment: I insist use SqlBulk in ADO.NET, as per your scenario entity does not get fit. I had same issue and resolved by not using entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [Snapshot Isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in SQL server, which in conjunction to setting the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT setting will change the behaviour you are seeing.

While a long-running transaction is in progress, instead of other tables being locked, they will see the rows in that table from before the transaction started.

To enable this:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

This is actually the default behaviour in Entity Framework 6 if your database was created by Code-First migrations.

Comment: Will they be able to import other datas too?

Comment: And why standard read committed level doesn't show previous committed entries and instead of that is blocking access?

Comment: Because Read Committed is not Read Committed Snapshot - that's the difference.  When using snapshot, multiple versions of affected rows are kept while a transaction is running.

Comment: The strange thing is that I'm using EF 6 with code first, but it is not enabled by default - any thoughts why that could be?

Comment: Did you create your DB manually?  This change only happens when the DB is created.